# Simple exponential $\\|e^{j\omega t}|$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry

I need help understanding this equation:
$\int_0^T |e^{j\omega t}|^2 dt$ = $\int_0^T 1.dt$ = T

0-T is only one period, not all T. 
$\ e^{j\omega t}$ is a periodic complex exponential and \omega  is the angular frequency.

$\ e^{j\omega t} = \cos\omega t + j\sin\omega t$

My question is how $\ |e^{j\omega t}|^2$ got evaluated to 1.

Thank you!

Comment: `\omega` is how to make an omega. The literal omega you used doesn't render in my web browser.  I had to look up character "A7B7".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does $|e^{ix}|^2 = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870729/why-does-eix2-1) – found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5C%20%7Ce%5E%7Bj%5Comega%20t%7D%7C%5E2%20%3D%201%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2):

With

$e^{ikx} = \cos kx + i\sin kx, \tag 1$

$\overline{e^{ikx}} = \cos kx - i\sin kx, \tag 2$

and

$\vert e^{ikx} \vert^2 = e^{ikx}\overline{e^{ikx}}$
$= (  \cos kx + i\sin kx)( \cos kx - i\sin kx)$
$= \cos^2 kx + \sin^2 kx = 1; \tag 3$

note that $i$ "disappears" when we multiply a complex number by its conjugate.  Indeed,

$ (\cos kx + i\sin kx)(\cos kx - i\sin kx)$
$= \cos^2 kx - i \cos kx \sin kx + i  \cos kx \sin kx + \sin^2 kx$
$= \cos^2 kx + \sin^2 kx = 1. \tag 4$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: My pleasure, my friend!

Answer (score 1):

$|sin x+j \cos x|^{2}=\sin^{2} x+\cos^{2} x=1$ for all real $x$ so $|sin x+j \cos x|=1$

Comment: Won't it be broken down into $ sin^2x + j^2cos^2x + 2*sinx*jcosx$ ? I'm confused about what happens to the j..
Thanks!

Comment: @RohanChandra $|a+jb|$ is **defined** as $\sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}$ when $a$ and $b$ are real.